# SUM Using Date Criteria from another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am looking to sum the number of Revenue and # of Product Placements based on the contract type (Month-to-month or long term) with date criteria in the future. For example, I want to know how much of our MRR is from MTM contract and from long term contract in 01/01/2019 and so on.

We have 2 type of contracts: Month to month (MTM), and long term. Our customer contracts converts into MTM (MTM Expiring Month) when they expire, so we are trying to visualize exactly how much will be convert into MTM in the future. MRR is Monthly Recurring Revenue, so essentially it's revenue.

What I am trying to calculate

IF MRR Exiting Month (e.g 2019-04-01) > Month (e.g 2019-01-01) THEN SUM MRR. This is Month to month recurring revenue.

IF MRR Exiting Month (e.g 2019-01-01) < Month (2019-02-01) SUM MRR. This is long term MRR

Here is my data table:

```
Companies | Placement |  MRR  | Start_Date | term_length | MRR_Exiting_Month
ANTON     | 2         |  300  | 2018-01-01 | 13          | 2019-02-01
ANKER     | 1         |  600  | 2018-07-01 | 6           | 2019-01-01
ANTON     | 2         |  300  | 2018-08-15 | 7           | 2019-02-01
ANTON     | 2         |  500  | 2018-10-01 | 5           | 2019-03-01
ANTON     | 2         |  300  | 2018-08-01 | 8           | 2019-04-01
```

I calculated the MRR_Exiting_Month using:

```
date_add(parse_date('%F',start_date), INTERVAL term_length MONTH) as contract_end_month
```

I use `generate_date_array` to populate the upcoming months in a different table, but not sure how to use case when from 2 different table without joining them. And I am expecting a result like this:

I am thinking about summing the MRR and Placement # if the MRR_Exiting_Month is greater than a given month in the future. Ideally the result table is like this:

```
Month      | MTM MRR   |  Long Term MRR  | 
2018-10-01 | 0         |  2000           | 
2018-11-01 | 0         |  2000           | 
2018-12-01 | 0         |  2000           | 
2019-01-01 | 600       |  1400           | 
2019-02-01 | 1200      |  800            | 
2019-03-01 | 1700      |  300            | 
2019-04-01 | 2000      |  0              | 
2019-05-01 | 2000      |  0              |
```

What would be the best way to do so in BigQuery? I appreciate the help!

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes, please provide example of input data and expected output. ideally present input data as WITH statement so we focus on your question and not on reproducing your data :o)

Comment: I will adjust the question accordingly. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I just edit the question. Please let me know if this is sufficient. Sorry I am still new to the coding world. Been reading the tutorial on stackoverflow but still have much more to learn

Comment: You still need to explain what is MTM, MRR, LongTerm, term_length and also what is the logic.

Comment: @MinhVu - it is much better now with data examples - but still not clear how to get to expected result. You should provide more details about your logic. if you have hard time to generalize it  - just explain how you got values for `MTM MRR` and `Long Term MRR` in ecah or at least few rows in your result

Comment: This explains why you need this, but please explain the logic! Read and follow my previous comment o:)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thank you guys for bearing with me.

We have 2 type of contracts: Month to month (MTM), and long term. Our customer contracts converts into MTM (MTM Expiring Month) when they expire, so we are trying to visualize exactly how much will be convert into MTM in the future. MRR is Monthly Recurring Revenue, so essentially it's revenue. 

What I am trying to calculate

IF MRR Exiting Month (e.g 2019-04-01) > Month (e.g 2019-01-01) THEN SUM MRR. This is Month to month recurring revenue.

IF MRR Exiting Month (e.g 2019-01-01) < Month (2019-02-01) SUM MRR. This is long term MRR

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I was in the middle of writing and I accidentally hit enter

Comment: why you have `2019-02-01` four times in your expected result vs. just having one last row `2019-02-01 | 2000      |  0` for that month?

Comment: I fixed it. Supposed to be increment. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH months AS (
  SELECT month
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-10-01', '2019-05-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) month
)
SELECT 
  month, 
  SUM(IF(MRR_Exiting_Month <= month, MRR, 0)) MTM_MRR,
  SUM(IF(MRR_Exiting_Month > month, MRR, 0)) Long_Term_MRR 
FROM months 
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY month
```

You can test, play with  above using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'ANTON' Companies, 2 Placement, 300 MRR, DATE '2018-01-01' Start_Date, DATE '2019-02-01' MRR_Exiting_Month UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ANKER', 1, 600, '2018-07-01', '2019-01-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ANTON', 2, 300, '2018-08-15', '2019-02-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ANTON', 2, 500, '2018-10-01', '2019-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ANTON', 2, 300, '2018-08-01', '2019-04-01' 
), months AS (
  SELECT month
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-10-01', '2019-05-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) month
)
SELECT 
  month, 
  SUM(IF(MRR_Exiting_Month <= month, MRR, 0)) MTM_MRR,
  SUM(IF(MRR_Exiting_Month > month, MRR, 0)) Long_Term_MRR 
FROM months 
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY month
-- ORDER BY month
```

with result

```
Row month       MTM_MRR Long_Term_MRR    
1   2018-10-01  0       2000     
2   2018-11-01  0       2000     
3   2018-12-01  0       2000     
4   2019-01-01  600     1400     
5   2019-02-01  1200    800  
6   2019-03-01  1700    300  
7   2019-04-01  2000    0    
8   2019-05-01  2000    0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! I will play around to see. Does it change anything if the MRR_Exiting_Month column does not exist in my original table? I had to calculate that column myself. 

Maybe using another subquery in this situation?

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot!